# Right-aligning and concatenating strings using Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have two questions regarding component layout using Sencha Touch 2:

- How can you right align text in a container?
- How can you concatenate different bits of dynamic data intermixed with static data into a component that needs to line wrap?

I have a view that I want to render like this:

[image: Desired view layout]

Where the "Seen:" text is static and right aligned, and the text on the right is a concatenated string with 3 dynamic pieces of text and two pieces of static text.

I have something that works, but it doesn't feel right.

```
xtype:'container',
    layout:{
    type:'hbox'
},
items:[
    {
        xtype:'container',
        flex:1,
        layout:{
            type:'hbox'
        },
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'spacer',
                layout:'fill'
            },
            {
                xtype:'label',
                layout:'fit',
                html:'Seen:'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        xtype:'label',
        name:'contentLabel',
        flex:5,
        html:'[BUILD A STRING AND SET THE HTML HERE]'
    }
]
```

**Right-aligning**

So to right-align the text, I basically used an hbox container with a spacer component on the left and a label on the right.  There's got to be an easier way.

**Concatenating**

I am able to build the string that I want to place on the right, but I'd rather have multiple labels that I can map one-to-one with my model.  It doesn't feel like MVC for me to have to write code to concatenate strings.

I tried breaking apart the right side into an hbox, but there were problems with line wrapping.  Each label wants to render itself individually, so if there were wrapping, it would happen within its own container.

Are there easier ways of doing what I am attempting?

Comment: For your concatenating issue, why don't you use a tpl like 'by {use} on {date}' and then set the data (using setData()) of the label once you get the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Right aligning:** it can be done with the `text-align` CSS property. In the example below I use the `style` property for simplicity, but using the `cls` property would be more flexible - it adds a CSS class to the component, so you can style it in the .sass file.

**Concatenating:** you can use the standard `join()` Javascript function. It concatenates all elements of an array into a string using the given separator. In my example dynamic1 and dynamic2 are variables.

So the result code:

```
xtype: 'container',
layout: {
    type: 'hbox'
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'label',
        flex: 1,
        html: 'Seen:',
        style: 'text-align:right'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        flex: 5,
        html: ['static1', 'static2', dynamic1, 'static3', dynamic2].join('')
    }
]
```

EDIT

You can also use the `tpl` property to define a template that renders `data` property. You can update it programatically calling container.setData()

```
xtype: 'container',
layout: {
    type: 'hbox'
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'label',
        flex: 1,
        html: 'Seen:',
        style: 'text-align:right'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        flex: 5,
        data: {
            name: 'Harry Potter',
            day: 'Saturday',
            date: 'October 21, 2011'
        },
        tpl: [
            '{name} on {day} {date}'
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: With regards to the string concatenation though, it still seems like we're building a string programmatically and then binding it to the container.  I'd rather have multiple controls that I bind individually so that if the UI designers decide that "We want to see 'Harry Potter' in italics and the date in a red font" everything will be disjoint.  Is there a way to do this with multiple controls?

Comment: Edited my answer, using this approach your controls can consume the same object, but use different templates

Comment: Thanks - that looks a lot more like what I'm trying to achieve!